# prevent rendering layouts from layout-sw360dp folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created 2 layout folders under res/layout

1) layout-hdpi-960x540
and 
 2) layout-sw360dp

the first folder i have created for motorola razr devices for the resolution of 960x540 devices. and the second folder i am using for google nexus device.
Now the problem i am facing is that the layouts under layout-sw360dp folder 
are being rendered for motorola device i.e( 960x540 of resolution ).

How can i get the  layouts rendered  from layout-hdpi-960x540  for the device of the resolution(960X540)?

Thanks

Comment: Having density-dependent layout resources (`-hdpi`) is bizarre. Having resolution-dependent layout resources (`-960x540`) is pointless, as those have been deprecated for years, are undocumented, were a terrible idea to begin with, and AFAIK do not work on modern devices.

Comment: if you have this in your minifest ,try to remove it and test 
android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: @CommonsWare so what is the solution you ll suggest.

Comment: I suggest coming up with a more flexible GUI design.

Comment: @CommonsWare, although I agree with pretty much everything you'll ever say, when you are trying to hit a Google Nexus 7 (tvdpi), having a sw600dp-tvdpi folder may be helpful and not all that bizarre if your app is very dependent on the exact posistioning of XML elements since it's a bizarre dpi. Not defining tvdpi if you're developing for other sw600dp devices might hurt in the long run, especially if you're testing on a Nexus 7 first and expecting it to look the same for other devices